# How to go about creating a new class of BufferedImage with a file as argument

Tags: java, constructor, bufferedimage

I want to create a new class ,because I want to make some new methods, which extends BufferedImage and takes a file ,a bmp picture, as an argument.
Like what happens here:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(dir + "coffeecup.png"));
```

Looking through the documentation I found that the class BufferedImage has two constructors:

1. public BufferedImage(ColorModel cm,WritableRaster raster,
            boolean isRasterPremultiplied,
            Hashtable properties)
2. public BufferedImage(int width,
            int height,
            int imageType)

Going through the documentation of all the arguments I failed to notice which argument refers to a file ,if any. 
So how would I need to go about in creating a new BufferedImage class but with a file as one of the arguments?

Comment: Why can't you just use `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(dir + "coffeecup.bmp"));`???

Comment: Because I want to create some additional methods.

Comment: Ok... What kind of methods and why? And what stops you? As it stands, it's very hard to guess what you are really asking for, or if what you want to do is even possible. The `BufferedImage` class doesn't have any methods to read from file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't trying an complicate matters. Unless you're trying to override some implementation (which I advise against) Follow the basic rule composition over inheritance. Just create a wrapper class instead of trying to extend BufferedImage Unnessarily. You are trying to combine concerns which is a horrible idea. BufferedImage can't be constructed with a file because that is not a concern of an Image. As stated about BufferedImage

> It manages the image in memory and provides methods for storing, interpreting, and obtaining pixel data.

That's all it should be concerned with. So make a wrapper class that you can add methods to do whatever

```
public class BufferedImageWrapper {
    private BufferedImage bufferredImage;

    public BufferedImageWrapper(File file) {
        try {
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // your methods here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I should probably state that I fully agree with @peeskillet, and would not recommend using what I suggest below. :-)

But if you really want to extend `BufferedImage`, you could do something like this (inspired by my old [EasyImage](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/EasyImage.java) class, which is in the sandbox for a reason...):

```
public class EasyImage extends BufferedImage {
    public EasyImage(File iput) throws IOException {
        this(ImageIO.read(input));
    }

    public EasyImage(BufferedImage image) {
        this(image.getColorModel(), image.getRaster());
    }

    private EasyImage(ColorModel cm, WritableRaster raster) {
        super(cm, raster, cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
    }

    public boolean write(String format, File output) throws IOException {
        return ImageIO.write(this, format, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ill heed peeskillet's answer and use his idea,but thx for your reply as well ,it has been quite useful as well. :)